# Modify a 4 digit number inside of a string and inserting colon

Tags: php, string, digits

I have a string and i want to modify all 4 digit numbers and inserting colon between. Example: 1320 will become 13:20

```
$data = "The time is 1020 and the time is 1340 and 1550";
```

I'm thinking to use `preg_match('/[0-9]{4}/', '????', $data);`

But not sure how to pass the same value again in the preg?

Comment: Your `preg_match` usage is backwards, parameter 2 is the string to search, parameter 3 is the match. You could do `$match[0] . $match[1] . ':' . $match[2] . $match[3]`. Answer below seems cleaner though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way could be to use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead and use  capturing groups to capture 2 times  2 digits `(\d{2})(\d{2})` between word boundaries `\b`

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups using `$1:$2`

```
$data = "The time is 1020 and the time is 1340 and 1550";
$data = preg_replace('/\b(\d{2})(\d{2})\b/', "$1:$2", $data);
echo $data;
```

Result:

```
The time is 10:20 and the time is 13:40 and 15:50
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/4dQFt)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use capture groups, you merely need to seek the qualifying 4-digit substrings and target the zero-length position in the middle of the substring.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/56TVP))

```
$data = "The time is 1020 and the time is 1340 and 1550";    
echo preg_replace('~\b\d{2}\K(?=\d{2}\b)~', ':', $data);
```

Output:

```
The time is 10:20 and the time is 13:40 and 15:50
```

`\b` is a word boundary which ensures you're match the first digit in the sequence
`\d{2}` matches the first two digits
`\K` "restarts the full string match" -- effectively forgets the previous two digits
`(?=\d{2}\b)` is a lookahead for two digits not followed by a digit.

`preg_replace()` replaces the zero-length position with the colon.

---

If you wanted to improve the validation with this replacement, you could specify some known character ranges like this:

```
echo preg_replace('~\b[0-2]\d\K(?=[0-5]\d\b)~', ':', $data);
```

Of course the above isn't 100% reliable because it would match times like `2900`.  Validating everything between `0000` and `2400` gets considerably hairier:

```
echo preg_replace('~\b(?:(?:(?:[01]\d|2[0-3])\K(?=[0-5]\d\b))|(?:24\K(?=00\b)))~', ':', $data);
```

*note, I don't like the inclusion of `2400`, but I have read arguments claiming that it is a valid time.  This is why I am including it.

If you want to omit `2400` as a valid value, then it is a bit more manageable (`0000` - `2359`):

```
echo preg_replace('~\b(?:[01]\d|2[0-3])\K(?=[0-5]\d\b)~', ':', $data);
```